# How to change the scrollbar slider position in QScrollArea by code itself, and not by mouse?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Normally, when I run the program the vertical scroll bar on MainWindow looks like this:

[image]

The scroll bar slider is at the very left, by default, and you can slide it all the way to the right.

**My Question is how do I set the default slider position in the center or further right so that when I start the program, the slider is already at the center, like this:**

[image]

Example Code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import time

class ExampleWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1200, 600)
            
        self.setWindowTitle("Checkbox")

        self.central_widget = QWidget()               
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)    
        
        

        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea(self.central_widget)
        self.scrollarea.setGeometry(0, 0, 1200, 700)
        self.scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.container = QWidget()
        
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.container)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.container)
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('map95.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        
        
        lay.addWidget(label)
        lay.addStretch()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = ExampleWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: 1. What you're showing is the *horizontal* scroll bar. 2. You're adding the scroll area to the central widget but no layout is set, and that's a serious problem because the bars can become invisible, and that's why fixed geometries should *always* be avoided, and [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) should be used instead. 3. The range of a scroll bar depends on various aspects, and you cannot *ever* be completely sure that the positioning is correct until the widget is *actually and finally* shown. 4. See [setValue](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#value-prop).

Comment: Please do not delete a post and create another post with the same content as the system may block your ability to create post and then you will complain.

Comment: @musicamante Yeah you're right. I figured it out using layouts. Thanks.